# Simple loop optimized by clang, how?

Tags: loops, optimization, clang

From [CppCon 2014: Mike Acton "Data-Oriented Design and C++"](https://youtu.be/rX0ItVEVjHc?t=2588), he shows this simple loop

```
int Foo::Bar(int count)
{
    int value = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        if ( m_NeedParentUpdate )
        {
            value++;
        }
    }
    return (value);
}
```

Being optimized by clang as such

[image]

I don't understand what is happening here. Why is this code bad, and why is it optimized as such by clang, why does this work?

About the loop, he also says "I'm sure you can optimize this in your head". I don't get it. How do I optimize this?

Comment: Please don't post pictures, copy or retype the text and post as code fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop increments `value` `count` times if `m_NeedParentUpdate` is not `false`.

From the generated code, it seems `m_NeedParentUpdate` is a boolean value stored as an unsigned byte at offset `0` from `this`. The optimizer probably detects that `m_NeedParentUpdate` is a constant in the loop, so the test can be moved outside the loop. The programmer should have written the code this way already and it might what Mike Acton refers to by *I'm sure you can optimize this in your head*.

Here is a rewritten version:

```cpp
class Foo {
    bool m_NeedParentUpdate;
    int Bar(int count);
};

int Foo::Bar(int count) {
    int value = 0;
    if (m_NeedParentUpdate) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            value++;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Note however that further optimizing the code *in your head* might lead to reducing the loop to `value += count;`, but this would be incorrect for negative values of `count`, which is not so obvious at first sight.

The optimizer may detect the loop pattern and optimize as:

```cpp
int Foo::Bar(int count) {
    int value = 0;
    if (m_NeedParentUpdate) {
        if (count >= 0) {
            value += count;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Or equivalently:

```cpp
int Foo::Bar(int count) {
    int value = 0;
    if (count >= 0) {
        if (m_NeedParentUpdate) {
            value = count;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Converting `m_ParentNeedUpdate` to an `unsigned` and negating it produces `0` for `false` and all bits one for `true`. Masking `count` with this value will produce `0` or `count`.

```cpp
int Foo::Bar(int count) {
    int value = 0;
    if (count >= 0) {
        value = -(unsigned)m_NeedParentUpdate & count;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Note however that the code still has a test and a branch instruction. It could be further optimized as:

```cpp
int Foo::Bar(int count) {
    // equivalent code, but definitely not readable
    return -(unsigned)m_NeedParentUpdate & -(unsigned)(count >= 0) & count;
}
```

Compiling this with both `gcc` and `clang` produces branchless code as can be seen on [GodBolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/p3efWV). But neither compiler reduces the original code to this one liner.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is considered bad is that you'll have to read the member variable `m_NeedParentUpdate` on every iteration. If this were a large `for` loop and you're trying to read a bunch of other member variables as well, then reading this `m_NeedParentUpdate` might take space in your cache, potentially reducing the effective cache usage. This would result in a performance penalty.

The specifics of performance penalty would depend on the data layout of the class running this code and what other member variables are accessed inside the `for` loop.

The way we can optimize this is to move the boolean check outside as we really need to do it only once.

```
int Foo::Bar(int count)
{
    int value = 0;
    if ( m_NeedParentUpdate )
    {
        for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
        {

            value++;
        }
    }
    return (value);
}
```